# How does numpy array typing interact with object?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy

I am currently trying to implement a datatype that stores floats in an numpy array. However trying to assign  an array with elements of this type with various lengths seems to obviously break the code. One would assign a sequence to an array element, which is not possible.

One can bypass this by using the data type object instead of float. Why is that? How could one resolve this problem using floats without creating a sequence?

Example code that does not work.

```
from numpy import *

foo= dtype(float32, [])
x = array([[2., 3.], [3.]], dtype=foo)
```

Example code that does work:

```
from numpy import *

foo= dtype(float32, [])
x = array([[2., 3.], [3., 2.]], dtype=foo)
```

Example code that does work, I try to replicate for float:

```
from numpy import *

foo= dtype(object, [])
x = array([[2., 3.], [3.]], dtype=foo)
```

Comment: Can you please clarify what you are trying to achieve?  What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I'm fairly sure the OP is hoping to make an element of the array be a sequence of floats--a list or tuple presumably

Answer (score 0):

The `object` dtype in Numpy simply creates an array of pointers to Python objects.  This means you lose the performance advantage you usually get from Numpy, but it's still sometimes useful to do this.

Your last example creates a one-dimensional Numpy array of length two, so that's two pointers to Python objects.  Both these objects happen to be lists, and Python list have arbitrary dynamic length.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you were trying to achieve with this, but note that

```
>>> np.dtype(np.float32, []) == np.float32
True
```

Arrays require the same number of elements for each row. So, if you feed a list of lists in numpy and all sublists have the same number of elements, it'll happily convert it to an array. This is why your second example works.

If the sublists are not the same length, then each sublist is treated as a single object and you end up with a 1D array of objects. This is why your third example works. Your first example doesn't work because you try to cast a sequence of objects to floats, which isn't possible.

In short, you can't create an array of floats if your sublists are of different lengths. At best, you can create an array of 1D arrays, since they are still considered objects.

```
>>> x = np.array(list(map(np.array, [[2., 3.], [3.]])))
>>> x
array([array([ 2.,  3.]), array([ 3.])], dtype=object)
>>> x[0]
array([ 2.,  3.])
>>> x[0][1]
3.0
>>> # but you can't do this
>>> x[0,1]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#18>", line 1, in <module>
    x[0,1]
IndexError: too many indices for array
```

If you're bent on creating a float 2D array, you have to extend all your sublists to the same size with `None`, which will be converted to `np.nan`.

```
>>> lists = [[2., 3.], [3.]]
>>> max_len = max(map(len, lists))
>>> for i, sublist in enumerate(lists):
    sublist = sublist + [None] * (max_len - len(sublist))
    lists[i] = sublist

>>> np.array(lists, dtype=np.float32)
array([[  2.,   3.],
       [  3.,  nan]], dtype=float32)
```